# Button click doesn't open new window

Tags: html, href, font-awesome

I have a font awesome icon `<i>` item inside a `a` href with a `target='_blank'` — yet only the text is clickable; clicking on the icon opens a new tab with `about:blank`, not the actual link.

```
<a href="..." class="not-light" target="_blank" style="display: block; ">
    <i class="fa fa-android"></i> »
</a>
```

How do I make the icon clickable as well?

For example, click the lightbulb in the footer of the http://ambieye.com/ site's footer.

Comment: i cant seem to recreate your issue http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waBGGX

Comment: Indeed, it may be an effect of the other css, or javascript on the site. Is it reproducible when clicked on in Chrome, or is it local to my machine?

Comment: no i get the error on your website which is totally crazy lol.  I put your entire footer inside my codepen still no issues.  it even works on the lightswitch....I get the same error on your <i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> in chrome BTW

Comment: Thanks, it was a problem with the javascipt handler local to the site after all, nothing to do with css/html, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the javascript handler, not the css/html; the way to find these issues is in Chrome's handlers section, under 'click handler' -

```
function handleSystemLink(a) {  
  var url = a.target.href;
```

The argument `a` was the `i` element which did not have `href`, thus openning a bad link.

Comment: Interesting so what is the way you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The `<li>` is a list. The list must be on the outer and the text in the inner like this :

```
<li style="display: block; ">
    <a href="..." class="not-light" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-android"></i> » The text
    </a>
</li>
```

Try it.